# InnerHTML with value

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I need a help on the below code. I need users enter their contents into placeholder, not in the script, so when the user click the button, the result can show up.

In this example, "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab" is the sample content, but I need to put them into placeholder, not in the script.

I change InnerHTML with value but it seems not working. Can anyone help? Thank you so much!

```
<body>

<p>Enter foregin character and click covert</p>

<input id="demo" placeholder="Keyword">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Convert</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURI(uri);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ids need to be unique. You are using the same id `demo` on the `<p>` element and on the `<input />` element.

Comment: sorry, its typo. should be demo and demo 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<p>Enter foreign character and click convert</p>

<input id="demo1" placeholder="Keyword"> <!-- different id from <p> tag -->

<button onclick="myFunction()">Convert</button>

<p id="demo2"></p> <!-- different id from <input> tag -->

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var uri = document.getElementById("demo1").value; // This was missing, get the value the user has typed
    var res = encodeURI(uri);
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfL10pxL/1/)

Comment: Thank you much! Wizard! It is working. Really appreciated! Not sure why is downvote.

Answer (score 1):

> You can set any value in the placeholder using script.

```
document.getElementById("xyz").placeholder = "Any value";
```

> Check this out at:
>   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_placeholder.asp